# convert strings to classes from drawing namespace

Tags: c#

I have an interace representing a dictionary. This interface takes strings as keys and values. I need to store some Fonts and Colors in there and read them later on. So for this collection only string types are possible.

Fortunately I can cast the `Color` and `Font` class to a string using `.ToString()` so

```
collection.Add("Font", font.ToString());
collection.Add("FontColor", fontColor.ToString());
```

will do the trick. When I read them from the collection unfortunately I can't cast the string back to Font / Color.

So for example

```
string rawFontColor = myColor.ToString();
Color fontColor = (Color)rawFontColor;

string rawFont = myFont.ToString();
Font font = (Font)rawFont;
```

will not work. What is the best way to convert them properly?

Comment: For Color, there is [Color.FromName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromname?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Use `Color.FromName()`

Comment: Why do you store these things as strings?

Comment: Take a look at [FontConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontconverter?view=netframework-4.8), it converts from string to font and vice versa.

Comment: Being picky; converting something to a string representation is not casting it to a string, it's converting. If you must represent complex types as strings, you'll need to store all the relevant info about the type so you can recreate it later on. For Color this is relatively easy - to some #FFEEAA rgb representation and back. For a font, that has a weight, slant, opacity, face, size... that's far more strings you're going to have to store.. I'd recommend, in the first instance, a different storage container that isn't string based..

Comment: @CaiusJard well this collection only takes strings so I have to convert it ...

Comment: I think the point being made by caius jard is that the ToString() method is not a serialisation method so you should not expect to be able to deserialise from that string back to an object. It is possible to serialise an object using XmlSerializer and store that document in a string, so maybe that is an avenue you might look down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enough information in the comments to be able to do this:

```cs
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
var collection = new Dictionary<string, string>();

collection.Add("Font", converter.ConvertToString(new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, 
                       FontStyle.Strikeout, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)));

collection.Add("FontColor", Color.Aqua.ToArgb().ToString());

Color fontColor = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(collection["FontColor"]));
Font font = (Font)converter.ConvertFromString(collection["Font"]);

Console.WriteLine(fontColor.Name);
Console.WriteLine(font.ToString());
```